# Nuxt.js using Vuetify and Vite causes "__createCJSModule__(...) is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, yarnpkg, vite

## The problem:

When creating a new Nuxt.js project using Yarn as the package manager and using Vuetify and Vite as build modules I get the following error in the browser (Google Chrome):

```
__createCJSModule__(...) is not a function
```

Also in my terminal I get the following warnings:

- `WARN  [vite:css] @charset must precede all other statements`
- `This version of postcss-preset-env is not optimised to work with PostCSS 8.`

These warnings repeat multiple times.

I created my project like so:

```
yarn create nuxt-app testapp
```

Output:

```
create-nuxt-app v4.0.0
✨  Generating Nuxt.js project in testapp
? Project name: testapp
? Programming language: JavaScript
? Package manager: Yarn
? UI framework: Vuetify.js
? Nuxt.js modules:
? Linting tools: (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to invert selection)
? Testing framework: None
? Rendering mode: Universal (SSR / SSG)
? Deployment target: Server (Node.js hosting)
? Development tools: jsconfig.json (Recommended for VS Code if you're not using typescript)
? What is your GitHub username? sam
? Version control system: Git
```

When this is completed I run `yarn add nuxt-vite` to add Vite to the project and add it under `buildModules` inside `nuxt.config.js`.

nuxt.config.js:

```
export default {
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/vuetify
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
    'nuxt-vite'
  ],
}
```

Then I cd into the project and run `yarn dev`. This then results in the multiple warnings and error message.

[Screenshot of the warnings inside terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gymCp.png)
[Screenshot of error message in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIiGi.png)

## Package versions:

These are the (dev)dependencies im using and their versions (copied from `package.json`):

```
"dependencies": {
  "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
  "core-js": "^3.19.3",
  "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
  "vue": "^2.6.14",
  "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.14",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
  "vuetify": "^2.6.1",
  "webpack": "^4.46.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.12.3",
  "nuxt-vite": "0.3.5"
}
```

## What I have tried so far:

#### Using yarn to add *older* modules:

After some searching on Google I found [this comment](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/8087#issuecomment-779874235) on an issue in the Nuxt.js Github repository. When using the yarn fix:

```
yarn add --dev css-loader@^5.0.0 postcss@^8.1.10 postcss-import@^13.0.0 postcss-loader@^4.1.0 postcss-url@^10.1.1
```

This gets rid of the first warning *`@charset must precede all other statements`* but the second warning and error are still there.

#### Downgrading nuxt-vite

I've also tried to downgrade the `nuxt-vite` version by changing to version number in `package.json` from `0.3.5` to `0.2`. After a `yarn install` this solution removes the error and I can visit the page, but the warnings in the console stay the same.

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that those two errors are unrelated, so for that matter, keep `nuxt-vite` downgraded as it solved the first error.

Regarding your two other errors.

> WARN  [vite:css] @charset must precede all other statements

This error means that Vite has an `@import` declaration that is not at the top of their file. That was restricted in previous esbuilds. so to solve this, you can do one of two things:

1. upgrade [esbuild](https://deps.dev/npm/esbuild) (`npm update esbuild`)
2. disable these restrictions in your `vite.config.js` by adding the code attached below to your file.

   ```
   css: {
   preprocessorOptions: {
     scss: {
       charset: false
     },
     less: {
       charset: false,
     },
   },
   charset: false,
   postcss: {
     plugins: [{
       postcssPlugin: 'internal:charset-removal',
       AtRule: {
         charset: (atRule) => {
           if (atRule.name === 'charset') {
             atRule.remove();
           }
         }
       }
     }],
   },
   }
   ```

and to fix

> This version of postcss-preset-env is not optimised to work with PostCSS 8.

you need to update `postcss-preset-env` as it has been [fixed](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-preset-env/pull/220) in one of their latest releases

Comment: When adding `nuxt-vite` to the project it does not add a `vite.config.js` file also when I create one it does nothing. In the [documentation](https://vite.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/config) for `nuxt-vite` it says that all the configuration should be in `nuxt.config.js`. So I added it there, but still get the same warnings.

Comment: I'll look at it, did it solve your second error though?

Comment: can you share your css? or just make sure all your import declaration there are at the top of the file?

Comment: The `postcss-preset-env` update did not work. But downgrading it to version 7 did. Also I don't have any CSS of my own. Just the default CSS from creating a Nuxt project with vuetify.